# finding the spectral family

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra

If an operator $$T\colon R^3\to R^3$$ is presented,with respect to an orthonormal basis,by a matrix

$ A= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1 
\end{bmatrix}
$.
What is the corresponding spectral family?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M = \left[ \matrix{-1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1} \right]$. Note that $M = M^T = M^{-1}$, and $MAM= \left[ \matrix{-1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1} \right]$. Thus, the eigenvalues of $A$ are $-1$ and $1$, and the projectors can be calculated by observing that $
ME_{-1}M = \left[ \matrix{
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0}
\right]
$
and $E_1 = I$.